# Since upgrading i am getting errors with my flutter in app web view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-inappwebview

I am getting these errors after upgrading my inappwebview in pubsec.yaml.

The named parameter 'initialOptions' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'initialOptions'.

The named parameter 'initialHeadersRequest' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'initialHeadersRequest'.

The named parameter 'debuggingEnabled' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'debuggingEnabled'.

The named parameter 'onWebViewCreated' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onWebViewCreated'.

The named parameter 'onLoadStart' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onLoadStart'.

The named parameter 'onLoadStop' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onLoadStop'.

CAN ANYONE HELP ME WITH THESE ERRORS???
I am not getting the migrations properly.

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
 import 'package:gec_app/Menu.dart';

 Future main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 }

 class AboutUs extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _AboutUsState createState() => new _AboutUsState();
 }

 class _AboutUsState extends State<AboutUs> {
 InAppWebViewController webView;

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 }

@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Visit Us'),
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
            })),
    body: Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
  url: Uri.parse("https://www.gecgh.org/"),
        initialHeadersRequest: {},
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(

          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              debuggingEnabled: true,
              preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP),
        ),
        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
          webView = controller;
        },
        onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
        onLoadStop:
            (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {},

      ))
    ])),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: did you fix it? i got the same error so annoying